# Searchview results are overlaping the keyboard

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-menu, searchview

I'm using the actionbarsherlock searchview, if i type a text in suggestion view i get set of results in dropdown, but if i scroll the suggestions, the entire suggestion view overlaps on my keyboard. How to prevent this

Here how the image looks

[image]

```
Menu.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


android:title="@string/ManageList"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"/>
```

This is how i'm crating menu in my activity.

```
  MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home_activity, menu);

        mSearchview = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        mSearchview.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        mSearchview.setFocusable(true);
        mSearchview.requestFocusFromTouch();

        if(mSearchadapter == null)
        {
            mSearchadapter = new SearchAdapter(getApplication(), null);
        }

        mSearchview.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSearchadapter);

        mSearchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if(newText.trim().equals(""))
               {
                   return false;
               }

               Cursor c = TaskController.getDBManager().getAllTasksForSuggestedFilter(newText);

               mSearchadapter.changeCursor(c);

               return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you solve this issue?